# Find my bottleneck with calling a command line tool with subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a C++ command line executable (not made by me) that takes some parameters and then connects to a server and downloads data from a database and outputs it line by line to the command line, it can also be passed a -o myfile.txt parameter to output the lines to a file.

One particular usage returns ~13million lines of data.

Instead of calling this and outputting to a file I call it with the python subprocess module in order to process the output lines and insert into a local sqlite3 table I make, as this suits my needs much better than a text file.

When I call the command line tool outside of python with -o to output to a file it takes 37 minutes due to the large volume of data needing to be processed and it has to download it over a network from the server with this data.

When I call it in python to process the lines into SQL, it takes me ~90 minutes. Almost 2x as much time.

I imagine my code has a bottleneck then and it can't process the incoming stdout lines as fast as it is receiving them, else it wouldn't have such a delay.

Is there an obvious issue in my code or how can I troubleshoot to find where my bottleneck is?

My code is here: https://pastebin.com/9DgmPdzj

The InitialiseTable() function and InitialConfigDone variable are used in order to create the table I need to store the data based on the first line of data content, I check if this InitialTable() has been done and if not then it just inserts the data. It does InitialiseTable for the first line then doesn't do it again.

```
def CaptureIntoSQL(host,table, InitialConfigDone=False):
    """Starts AdminDataCapture and redirects output to a table in a local SQL database"""


    command ="./MyCommandLineTool_x86-64_rhel6_gcc48_cxx11-vstring_mds -u {0} -p {1} -h {2} -t {3} --static -c".format(username,password,host,table)

    table_name ="{0}_Table{1}_{2}".format(host,table,GetDate())
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        cmdoutput = process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
        if cmdoutput == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if cmdoutput:
            data = cmdoutput.split("|") # split the output line into a list
            try:
                Symbol = data[5]
                if Symbol != "<Symbol>" and InitialConfigDone == False: # Run InitialiseTable() function to create the sqlite3 table, if it hasn't been done, once it's done once we don't want to do this again
                    try:
                        InitialiseTable(table_name,data)
                        InitialConfigDone = True
                        logger.info("Table created for {0}".format(table_name))
                    except:
                        logger.info("InitialiseTable(table_name,data) failed:\n table_name: {0} \n data: {1}".format(table_name,data))


                elif Symbol != "<Symbol>" and InitialConfigDone == True: # If we've already ran InitialiseTable() begin inserting data.
                    Permission = data[3]
                    exchangeCode = data[5].split(".")[-1]
                    if exchangeCode == "":
                        exchangeCode = "."
                    else:
                        pass
                    valuelist = data[7::2]
                    valuelist.insert(0, Permission)
                    valuelist.insert(0, exchangeCode)
                    valuelist.insert(0, Symbol)
                    InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO '{0}' VALUES{1}".format(table_name, vtuple) # my query to insert into my sqlite table
                    try:
                        c.execute(InsertQuery, valuelist)
                    except:
                        pass

            except:
                pass
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: If you're code is working, this should be posted on Code Review, not here.

Comment: One obvious thing that would speed it up is to generate prepared, parameterized statements for the inserts rather than generating unique SQL for each row.  If I recall, this might mean using `executemany` in Python.  Your code is also syncronous, processing data sequentially as you get it.  Of course it will take extra time for parsing, analyzing and then saving it back into another local database.

Comment: try to perform bulk inserts, this should speed up a little, but entering data into an sql database is not for free so  not sure how much you can shave off

Comment: How hard is implementing asyncronous to take in my data and insert it at the same time? ill look into that next..